# Can't override bootstrap style with my own stylesheet

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, razor, overriding

**ASP MVC RAZOR**

I try to override the bootstrap default style. I declared my stylesheet as below:

```
 /*bootstrap and default style*/
 @Styles.Render("~/Content/css");
 /*My CSS*/
<link href="@Url.Content("~/css/main.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
        @RenderSection("Styles", required: false)
```

In the bundleconfig:(only the default styles)

```
       bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css" ));
```

But as you can see below my style is overriden by bootstrap .

[image: Inspector]

I thought it has something to do with the order of the style in the head tag. But mine comes after bootstrap so it should work...

I copy the full layout page so you can check what's going on.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css");
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/css/main.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    @RenderSection("Styles", required: false)



</head>
<body>

    <div class="cachetop col-lg-12 navbar-fixed-top"></div>
    <div class=" topmenubar navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top ">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                <a class="navbar-left " href="@Url.Action("Accueil","Home")">
                    <img src="@Url.Content("../img/minilogo.png")" />
                </a>

            </div>
            <div class=" navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="menuitembar nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="menuitem nav-item active">@Html.ActionLink("Notre carte", "pizzas", "Carte", null, new { @class = "nav-link" })</li>
                    <li class="menuitem nav-item">@Html.ActionLink("Nous trouver", "Localisation", "Home", null, new { @class = "nav-link" })</li>
                    <li class="menuitem nav-item">@Html.ActionLink("Un peu d'histoire", "Histoire", "Home", null, new { @class = "nav-link" })</li>
                    <li class="menuitem nav-item">@Html.ActionLink("Travailler chez Michel", "Workwith", "Home", null, new { @class = "nav-link" })</li>

                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <div class="text-center">
                <p>

                </p>
            </div>
        </footer>

    </div>


    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @RenderSection("Javascript", required: false)
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add `!important` to your css

Comment: You may need to add your main css before bootstrap

Comment: By adding !important it's working.. but is it the proper way to do ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you make your CSS selectors more specific, there is a level of [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) that determines which styles get applied.  So doing:

```
li.menuitem { color: black; }
```

Makes it more specific.  Also adding [!important](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/) indicates that this style would have priority:

```
.menuitem { color: black !important; }
```

Careful with nested CSS hierarchies and using !important.  It could cause issues if you want to override those changes in a different context.  Only use when necessary, but it's OK to use.

Answer (score 1):

I've finally managed to do it without using `!important`

```
ul.menuitembar.nav.navbar-nav li.menuitem a{
    color:black;
}
```

So the specificity need to be considered.

Thank you Brian